# Configure flex sandbox for server local files

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I developed a flex application that loads images from the fileSystem. You just specify the path to the image, then the app brings some data from local webservices, and then flex loads the image and shows them to the user in an specific way.

I tested it by running the application from FlashBuilder as a WebApplication... so far no problems at all. However when loading the swf from a webpage, on a deployment environment (I.E: JBoss as the web application server) it doesn't loads anything...

My guess is that since now the swf is on the web server context, it can't load files from the local filesystem (I.E: /Users/username/files/myFile.jpg)... is this correct?? If it is... then what should I do in order to load the files correctly?? Or should I upload the files on the server first and then set the file path to an URL pointing to my web server resources?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is able to interact with the users file system without the need for httpservice middle ware. Meaning, I go to your your webpage with your flex app, I am able to load images from my filesystem to view in the app. However, if you want to the user to view images from the server that hosts the swf then you will need httpservice calls to a php, jsp, perl scripts or the like to get the data from your server.